# SQL insert for range of values

Tags: sql, database

I am creating a test database for school as a prototype database before I build the interface. there is a table called hands with 5 different hands with the primary key hand_id. The next table is called session that has session that includes a field hands that would have multiple hand_ids inside it.

insert into sessions (session_id, hands)
values (0000001, ????????);

I want the value of hands to include a range like 001-005 is there a way to put it in without individually typing them into a string like "001,002,003,004,005" also is there a way to reference the individual values inside the range with a select statement?

Example:

Session table: 
Session_id (pk)       Hands
001.                          01, 02, 03, 04
002.                           05, 06, 07
003.                          08, 09

Hands table: 
Hand_id.     Hand_data1.   Hand_data2
01.                "Some data".        "Some data" 
02                "Some data".        "Some data"
03                "Some data".        "Some data"
04                "Some data".        "Some data"
05                "Some data".        "Some data"

Basically hands includes an array of foreign keys to the hands table using hand_id

Comment: This is a classic tally (or numbers) table problem. If you have a table with the numbers from 1-1000 in it (a numbers or tally table) and you join to it using between, you get 5 records. There are many ways to easily generate data in SQL but perhaps you could post some more sample data so no one wastes time posting a solution that is not suitable.

Comment: If you're at the design validation stage, I suggest you stop storing arrays in a single database field. This will almost always cause problems later on. I don't understand your application or the nature of 'hands' in this case so I can't tell if it is part of the 1% where it might be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking - a notation for inserting a range of values into a column of a record - isn't generally supported. Here's a little background on why:

What you are describing is a one-to-many relationship. (Well, that is unless multiple sessions can include the same hand; then it's a many-to-many relationship.)

To a programmer it's natural to think of this in terms of arrays; but generally this isn't how it's done in a relational database; so standard sql doesn't have array support.

A few relational databases do have array types with varying degrees of support, but in general the rule is that each column has one value per row.

If each hand belongs to just one session, then instead of putting a `hands` value to `session` you would put a `session_id` column on the `hand` table.

Otherwise (if a hand can relate to many sessions) you would want a cross reference table with just `hand_id` and `session_id`. Then this cross reference would have 5 rows for a session that has 5 hands.

Following these patterns relates to one of the most basic normalization rules: no multi-value columns. Adhering to normalization rules will make everything easier on the long run

Comment: Thanks, this explains it. I have my schema messed up and I will redesign